# Subquery in MySQL WHERE clause using

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I'm not a sql guru at all but why does this query return error?

```
SELECT username FROM history as h 
    WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND updated>1342555201 AND updated<1342641599
    AND WHERE (SELECT status FROM managers WHERE username=h.username) > 0
```

How to group out usernames with status>0 in one query using the subquery on second table containing statuses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT h.username FROM history  h 
INNER JOIN status s USING(username)
WHERE h.updated BETWEEN 1342555201 AND 1342641599
GROUP BY h.username
HAVING  s.status > 0
```

**Note :**

- [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) will always retrive NOT NULL and common value of username
- i assume that both table have *same column name*.if both table have different column name then change

  `USING(username)` with `ON h.column_name = s.column_name`

Answer (score 2):

you should not have 2 WHERE statements

edit:

also - you should JOIN the manager table

Comment: oops. I'm so inattentive. Thank you

Comment: SELECT username FROM history as h 
    INNER JOIN managers m USING(username)
    WHERE AND m.status > 0
          AND h.updated BETWEEN 1342555201 AND 1342641599

Comment: I can't join because in real db I will have two columns with different names (`username` and `manager`)

Comment: you can still use JOIN with different column name. see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You have one `where` too many.

```
SELECT username FROM history as h 
WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND updated>1342555201 AND updated<1342641599
AND WHERE (SELECT status FROM managers WHERE username=h.username) > 0
    ^^^^^
```